# Android, BNO055 sensor automatic disconnect

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on a project that takes real-time values from the Adafruit BLE sensor BNO055 and process it further. The connection is all set and working and I can get the Fused Data, but only for a small amount of time. Upon seeing a pattern in the disconnection, I found out that the sensor gets automatically disconnected in somewhere around 150 seconds after establishing connection.

I'm not sure whether it's something to do with the sensor itself, like it's hardcoded to disconnect if no 'feedback' is obtained in some 'x' seconds, or it's a feature of Android classes itself. I'm attaching herewith, a screenshot of my logcat when the 'disconnection takes place.
[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJxhp.png). Also, here is a skimmed version of the logcat:

```
onNotify() - Device=DE:DA:53:31:02:E0 UUID=6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e srvcType=0 srvcInstId=0 charInstId=0
05-24 18:37:58.541 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.541 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.541 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.541 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.562 D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
05-24 18:37:58.563 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.563 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.564 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.568 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=1 device=DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.568 D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: DE:DA:53:31:02:E0
05-24 18:37:58.569 D/BLE: Disconnected from GATT server.
05-24 18:37:58.575 D/BNO: DISCONNECT_MSG
05-24 18:37:58.575 D/BluetoothGatt: close()
05-24 18:37:58.575 D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=1
05-24 18:37:58.577 D/BLE: mBluetoothGatt closed
```

Not sure what exactly the problem is, I'm sure the experts here would be able to help me!

Thanks,
Sriram

**UPDATE**: Downloaded apps(Bluetooth LE Scanner, BluefruitLE, BLE Scanner..) from playstore. Same issues persist with the apps as well, with the sensor disconnecting from the app after the same 150 seconds gap. Looks like this is a feature(?) in the sensor itself. Is there any way to overcome this, like saying it not to disconnect?

**UPDATE 2**: The disconnection seems to occur only in my Phone(Alcatel Onetouch Flash, Bluetooth v4.0) but works fine on my other tablet(Asus Google Nexus 7, Bluetooth v3.0) without disconnections. Is it(Bluetooth version), or any driver issue of any concern?

Comment: It seems your code executes the disconnect method of the GATT object, that's why it is being disconnected. Are you saying you are not doing this?

Comment: Also, if it could help, the Ble background stuff was(BleService.java) made from the Nordic Semi file here: [link](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-BLE-Joiner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/nrfblejoiner/ble/BLEService.java)

Comment: @Emil I'm sure the disconnect is not intentional, in fact, the only two places where this are called are 1. If the device itself is not supported 2.When the Disconnect button is pressed. Also, it occurs constantly at about 150 seconds after connection